# Cannot process the message because of the exception 'application/soap+xml; was not the expected type 'application/soap+msbin1'

Tags: java, wcf, soap1.2

I have made import classes through WS Import and then place in eclipse . The problem is that I  cannot process the message because of Unsupported media type . The problem is

> 'application/soap+xml; was not the expected type 'application/soap+msbin1'.

I know that we are requesting the service through Soap1.2 but service is asking from the WCF format but how can I solve this problem? Can anyone tell me how to change the application/soap+xml to application/soap+msbin1 through annotation not XML? I went through number of solution on web but couldn't get it to work, issues the problem is below?

> The server sent HTTP status code 415: Cannot process the message
>   because the content type
>   'application/soap+xml;charset="utf-8";action="http://tempuri.org/IReceiveNoteService/ReceiveNote"'
>   was not the expected type 'application/soap+msbin1'.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @il_raffa for showing interest. Below is mine Sample client code

`/* Simply initializing the object for the service class*/
/* Create Resware Web Service Client... */
ReceiveNoteService receiveNoteService = new ReceiveNoteService();

/* Created Web Service by calling simple service*/
IReceiveNoteService port = receiveNoteService.getCustomBindingIReceiveNoteService();

/* Calling function and printing the response of service*/
/* Line where i am getting exception*/
System.out.println("Server response: " + port.receiveNote(newReceiveNoteData()));`

I cannot provide my WSDL File because of its privacy issue